# Wi-Fi icon next to apps in android market

Tags: applications, google-play-store

In Android market some app have a Wi-Fi icon next to them.
Some examples are Cordy, Fieldrunners HD, Flight Control, Where's My Water?, Wind-up Knight, World of Goo.

What dose it mean that these apps have this icon next to them?

I'm using Galaxy Nexus.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It means that a Wi-Fi connection is strongly recommended to download them. This is usually because the apps are very large, such as World of Goo which is ~48 MB.

The newest version of the Market (v3.4.4 as of writing) displays a warning that lets you download it anyway, but I think that older versions just wouldn't let you download at all via a cellular connection (not positive on that, but I seem to recall seeing it myself).

Answer (score 8):

It means you can only download those apps when your phone is on a WiFi connection.

If you're on 3G and you attempt to load one of those (I tried Cordy) you'd get the following message:

> Download required Wi-Fi This download may be too large to be made over
>   a mobile connection. It is likely to remain paused until you are on
>   Wi-Fi.