# What does it mean the "WIFI" label on the market?

Tags: google-play-store, wi-fi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Wi-Fi icon next to apps in android market](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17210/wi-fi-icon-next-to-apps-in-android-market)

I've noticed that a few items on "My applications" on the Android Market client have a gray "WIFI" label on them. What does that mean?

Comment: For example: Flight control, Frontline commando

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Usually means it's a large file and requires you to be connected to WiFi to download.

http://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/mnfwa/what_does_the_wifi_label_mean_for_apps_on_the/

Answer (score 4):

You need WiFi to download the app. It could be that the app size is "LARGE", and a download via carrier network is not recommended.